# opencv haartraining didnt finish

Tags: opencv, training-data, haar-classifier

i use 1292 positive image its for face
and 5712 negative image

and this my code for harrtraining

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_haartraining.exe -data cascades -vec vector/facevector.vec -bg negative/bg.txt -npos 1033 -nneg 5712 -nstages 20 -nsplits 2 -nonsym -minhitrate 0.999 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -mem 1024 -mode ALL -w 24 -h 24 PAUSE
```

its 20 stage and its finish stage 6 on stage 7 it still like this in image
for 1 day 
i think its will still like this for ever what the problem 
the face on positive image its Clear

and this is a snip of positive image i used it

[image: problem haartraining]
<sub>(source: [imagetitan.com](http://img4.imagetitan.com/img4/IP8ACd1QZVLmh80/12/12_capture.jpg))</sub>

![haartraining still like this ][1]

[image: positive image]
<sub>(source: [imagetitan.com](http://img4.imagetitan.com/img4/IP8ACd1QZVLmh80/12/12_capture759.jpg))</sub>

![snip of positivae image i used it][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your min hit rate and maxFalseAlarm rate.

I would suggest using something like 0.4 & 0.95 to get going.

reason for this is that it will take forever for it to hit 0.999 & 0.5 if ever (if finish at all)

Comment: did it will make my cascade weak ?

Comment: also can i change min hit rate and maxFalseAlarm rate and start form stage 7

Comment: It will make it weaker, yes, but if you get more stages thats a good thing. And if you start a train with stages already in teh folder it will start from there. So if you already have 7 completed it will start from there